# Create RDD in scala and spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master("local")
      .appName("SparkAndHive")
      .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/tmp/spark-warehouse 2")
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()

    GeoSparkSQLRegistrator.registerAll(spark.sqlContext)



    val sparkConf: SparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark RDD foreach Example").setMaster("local[2]").set("spark.executor.memory", "2g")

    def displayFiles(files: Array[File], a: util.List[String], b: util.List[String]): Unit = { 
      for (filename <- files) { // If a sub directory is found,

        if (filename.isDirectory) if (filename.getName.contains("fire")) {
          rds.add(filename.getAbsolutePath)
          println(filename.getAbsolutePath)
        }
        else if (filename.getName.contains("water")){
          rdd.add(filename.getAbsolutePath)
          println(filename.getAbsolutePath)
        }
        else {                     
          displayFiles(filename.listFiles, a, b)
        }
      }
    }

    val files = new File("C://folder").listFiles

    val list1 = new util.ArrayList[String]
    val list2 = new util.ArrayList[String]

    displayFiles(files, list1, list2)

    val a= Seq(list1)
    println(a)
    val b= Seq(list2)
    println(b)
        
    
    val rdd1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(a))
    rdd1.foreach(println))

    val rdd2 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(b))
    rdd2.foreach(println))
```

I printed the list of subdirectory paths that ends with `_fire` and `_water`.
Then I created a list to store the paths that ends with `_fire` in one list and `_water` in another list.
I have created the RDD's for all the directories that are stored in both lists using a `foreach` loop.
When I am declaring a variable for the `foreach` loop and printing it, it is showing an empty list

**Question: How to all the RDD's into single RDD i.e., one for `_fire` and another for `_water`?**

Answer (score 0):

You can create them more directly. The issue in your code is that `displayFiles` isn't actually returning anything, or modifying `list1` or `list2`. Therefore, those lists will be empty, and so will `a` and `b`.

Instead, you can try something like:

```
val sc = spark.sparkContext
val basePath = "C://folder/"
val rddWater = sc.textFile(basePath + "*_water")
val rddFire = sc.textFile(basePath + "*_fire")
```

The above will get just all the contents of all the files matching the globs/paths matching the wildcards. Or, if you need to also figure out the file paths corresponding to each record, you can use `sc.wholeTextFiles`.

```
val rddWater = sc.wholeTextFiles("*_water")
val rddFire = sc.wholeTextFiles("*_fire")
// inspect contents using rddWater.collect() or rddFire.collect()
```

This site has more examples: https://sparkbyexamples.com/apache-spark-rdd/spark-read-multiple-text-files-into-a-single-rdd/